# need help on javadocx

Tags: java

I need to create ms-word document by using java.there is some components in doc file like..table of contents,header,footer,footnote,images,tables,paragraphs etc.

I found that javadocx will meet this requirement but when i downloaded free version for that..i cant able to add images in doc file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [JasperReports](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net) which have pretty good and usable design tool [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) and ability to export in `.docx` format.